# `const char*' to `char'

Tags: c++, string, pointers, comparison, countdown

I am new to programming and attempted to improve on my basic countdown timer. I don't know why I'm getting this error and other questions are in different situations and therefore don't suit my program.

```
//countdown timer using while loops, if else, strings and sleep

#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    char progend[5];
    float a; /* a will be floating point */
    cout << "Enter start the the number you want to count down from" << ".\n";

    while (a>-1) { /* the main program is located here */

        cin >> progend[5];

        if (progend[5] = "end") /* if the user inputs end the program ends */
        {
            a = -1;
        }

        else if (progend [5] = "start")
        {
            cin >> a;
            while (a>0) { /* the actual countdown timer*/
                Sleep(100);
                a = a - 0.1;
                cout << a;
            }

            cout << "Finished!" << ".\n" << "Enter start then enter another number to count down                 from or enter end to close the program" << ".\n";
        }

        else
        {
            cout << "Enter yes or end";
        }

    }
return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And `progend[5]` is too short for the string `'start'` - no place for terminating nul character

Comment: "getting this error" - please consider adding the *full* eror message the next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to assign a `char*` to `char`, I'm assuming you want to compare .

So use [`strstr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr)

```
if (strstr(progend,"end" )){
//...

}
```

Similarly all other places

But why not use `std::string` , when using C++

```
std::string progend;

if(progend.find("end") != std::string::npos)
{

}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
char progend[5];
...
if (progend [5] = "start")
```

tries to assign string literal `"start"` to 6th character of `progend` array (which doesn't even exist). Note that even if this code tried to assign a character, writing into the array after its end would cause *undefined behavior*.

You could either use C-style `strcmp`:

```
if (strcmp(progend, "start") == 0)
```

or yet even better: since this is C++, use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) objects instead:

```
std::string progend;
...
if (progend == "start") ...      // <-- this will use std::string::operator==
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a `const char *` to a `char` variable in

```
if (progend[5] = "end")
```

`progend[5]` is an element of a char array that holds a char value. `"end"` cannot be assigned to it.

You can use `std::string`. Then compare it like

```
std::string progend;
...
if(progend == "end")
{
    //your code
```

Comment: Its assignment, not comparation!

Comment: I don't see any comparison

Comment: So how do I change that?

Comment: @BenClayton, Use `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

You made a number of different errors.

```
cin >> progend[5];
```

Here, you ask for a character input, instead of a string. What is more, index 5 is out of the bounds of the array (we start counting from 0).

```
progend[5] = "start"
```

Here, there are two errors. To compare for equality, you sholud use `==` instead of `=`. What you actually did is try to assign a value. What is more, `"start"` is a C-type String, or better a pointer to the first character of the String.

Why don't you simply use a String from the C++ STL?

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// etc.

String progend;
```

Also, replace all instances of `progend[5]` with `progend`, you are not refering to a specific position. Equality check must also be `==`.

I hope this helps!!! :D